# Deadlock in fetch routine

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, grand-central-dispatch, synchronized

i am stuck with my first GCD and first core-data using application =)

two views access the same data (which is handled by a single DAO).

if i wait for the current view to finish loading its content no problem occors when changing view.

however: if i change the view (its tabbased) while one controller tries to fetch data from my model, the new controller tries the same and the threads 'collide' and my application freezes.

the freeze occurs in this line of code of my DAO:

```
    NSArray *results = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&error];
```

`reloadAllMonth()` accesses the fetch routine of my DAO

how i load the data in the first controller:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void) {
                [self reloadAllMonth];

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {                        
                    [self.allMonthTable reloadData];    
                });
```

in the second viewcontroller the first thing i do is update my DAO, this of course uses (beneath others) the very same fetch routine i called before:

```
    [self.dataHandler updateData];
```

i have tried two approaches so far:

**first** using a c-semaphore:

```
-(NSArray *)fetchAllMonthExpenses{  
    //@return: array of all expenses in month (day & month type)


    NSNumber *monthNumber = [self getMonthNumber:[NSDate date]];
        NSEntityDescription *exp = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Expense" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetch = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
    [fetch setEntity:exp];
    [fetch setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"month == %@",monthNumber]];
    NSError *error = nil;
    sem_wait(&isLoading);
    NSArray *results = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&error];  
    sem_post(&isLoading);
    return results;

}
```

**second** using the synchronized directive

```
-(NSArray *)fetchAllMonthExpenses{  
    //@return: array of all expenses in month (day & month type)


    NSNumber *monthNumber = [self getMonthNumber:[NSDate date]];
        NSEntityDescription *exp = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Expense" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetch = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
    [fetch setEntity:exp];
    [fetch setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"month == %@",monthNumber]];
    NSError *error = nil;
    @synchronized(self.class){
        NSArray *results = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&error];  
        return results;
    }    
}
```

sadly both of the approaches did not work, the application freezes whatever i do.

so my question is: what am i doing wrong (as i mentioned first time using threads), what am i missing, where should i look?

this has been keeping me busy for 2 days now and i cant seem to wrap my head around it :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `NSManagedObjectContext` and all of the `NSManagedObjects` inside it are not thread safe.

Whatever thread you use to create the context, that needs to be the *only* thread where you do *anything* relating to that context. Even just reading values from one of the managed object must be done *on that thread* and not on any other thread.

If you need two threads which both deal with the same database, you've got two options:

- use `dispatch_sync()` to jump into the other thread momentarily to perform all read/write operations on the managed objects and/or the context

Or:

- create a second `NSManagedObjectContext` in the other thread for the same database, and keep any changes made to the two contexts in sync.

The first option is much easier, but may remove much of the benefits of threading. The second option is harder, but it can be done, and there is a fairly good API for keeping two contexts on different threads in sync.

Lookup the Core Data Programming Guide for more details.

Comment: hi thank you for the quick answer =) i didnt know about dispach_sync - does it have the same effect as the @synchronized directory?

Comment: hi - sadly i was not able to achieve a non-hanging version with the dispatch_sync() function. the same effect was present. i was able to solve the problem algoritmically by decreasing the loading time from 2-3 secs down to 0.01 seconds, i dont think users will realise that nothing happens for so long ;)

Comment: Not sure what your problem is, or how @synchronized differs from dispatch_sync(). Can you post the your updated code? I think you are misunderstanding which parts must be done on the main thread, and which can be done on a background thread.

Comment: i put the part where i fetch data from my DAO in `reloadAllMonth` into dispatch_sync(mainqueue..) braces, everything else i did in the second thread..

Comment: I think all of your code needs to be done on the main queue/thread, including building the fetch request and reading the results of the fetch. Try removing your background queue altogether, and just doing it all on the main queue.

Comment: by the way, why are you using a background thread, and then doing the fetch request on the main thread? the fetch request is the only slow part of the code you have posted. if you want it on a background thread, then you have to create a second context for that thread. seems like you should be able to just stop using threads and your problem goes away, without creating any performance issues.

Comment: i have actually stopped using threads now. but since the fetch is done in the main thread, and the interface is updated in the main thread as well i have the problem that i am somehow not able to display a progressview while loading the data :/